# Setup heroku environment on different machine

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I have two laptops, one work laptop and another personal laptop. I have setup the Heroku environment on the work laptop. In git repo I have added github as origin and heroku as separate remote. Whenever I need to deploy anything I just use `heroku` remote to push my changes.
Now I have already cloned my code from github and also installed heroku-toolbelt on the second laptop. Now I want to push my code and access Postgres database from second laptop. But not sure how to do it. I am able to see the app config parameter by this command.

```
heroku config --app <MY-APP-NAME>
```

But when I try to access database I am not able to do so. The `pg` sub-command doesn't provide `--app` option to specify the app name.
I tried to look into `heroku fork` but this command will basically create another app from an existing app. I don't want to do this. 
I also looked into `herku git:clone` but this command will basically clone the repo. I have already cloned my repo from `githu`.
I am not sure how to have the same `heroku` enviornment as I have on my work laptop.

**EDIT1**

I executed the following command to add heroku remote in git config.

```
heroku git:remote -a <MY-APP-NAME>
```

So I don't need to specify the `--app` option to access the config. It automatically picks the right config. But I when I try to access the Postgres database it gives me following error.

```
>heroku pg:psql
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
sh: psql: command not found
```

This exact same command works on another laptop.

**EDIT2**

I figured out the problem. Actually `heroku` is trying to run `psql` on my local box but `psql` was not installed on my machine and hence it couldn't successfully connect to remote database. So I executed the following command to install `psql` and it worked like charm.

```
brew install postgres
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add the git remote by executing the following line.

```
heroku git:remote -a <MY-APP-NAME>
```

Then make sure your system has the `postgres` client installed. If it is not installed then installed it using the following command.

```
brew install postgres
```

The above command is only valid for Mac which has `brew` installed. You can search internet to find the specific command for your own platform.